# how much can i have on a 20 amp breaker?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a 20 amp breaker, with two lights and a outlet in on it, (the outlet normally runs stereo equipment), can i add another outlet for a tv and a fan?

Answer (score 2):

Add up the wattage on the lights, the stereo gear, the fan, and the TV, then divide by 120 and see if it's more than 20 -- although unless you have a monster amp on your stereo, I doubt you'll run into trouble there.

As to the receptacle itself, it's fine -- Code only apportions 180VA per receptacle yoke or lighting outlet.

Comment: Note: 180VA per receptacle,  is only used in commercial and industrial load calculations. It may be a good rule of thumb, but in residential applications it's not a code requirement.

Comment: @Tester101 -- yeah, it's the fallback number Code uses when there's not another means of load calculation specified (which makes it a *really awesome* rule of thumb :)